# Install a PEAR package without an Internet connection

Tags: php, packages, localhost, pear

I'm trying to install a package via PEAR, PHPUnit to be precise. However, the server I'm using is not connected to the Internet.

I managed to find a `.tgz` of `PHPUnit` in its `PEAR` repository at : [PEAR PHPunit-3.7](http://pear.phpunit.de/get/PHPUnit-3.7.22.tgz)
(although it's not the latest version, 3.8)

When I tried to put this on the server, I ran `pear install PHPUnit-3.7.22.tgz` but I got:

```
Unknown channel "pear.phpunit.de"
Parsing of package.xml from file "/var/tmp/pearUdSQzm/package.xml" failed
install failed
```

So what do I need to do instead?

Answer (score 3):

I had to use the the -O (offline) parameter of pear

```
pear install -O /path/to/packet.tgz
```

in order to stop pear trying to connect to `pear.php.net` first.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from downloading the packages, you need to download all dependencies and install them first.

Before you can do that, you need to register the channels. For each channel you have packages from, download `/channel.xml` and use `pear add channel.xml` to register it.

Then you can install the package `.tgz` file without problems.

Answer (score 1):

Use the full path of the file

For Example :

```
pear install /path/to/PHPUnit-3.7.22.tgz
```

Comment: Parsing of package.xml from file "/var/tmp/pearS8fPmM/package.xml" failed
install failed.

At least it didn't try to connect to the Internet this time.

Comment: Thanks! This is how I install OCI8: `pear install /tmp/oci8-1.4.10.tgz`